# How to remove entry from ArrayList in sync with Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Database:

[image]

I have a ArrayList `usersList` with class `UsersOnlineClass`:

```
public class UsersOnlineClass {

    private String muserName;

    public UsersOnlineClass(String userName) {
        muserName = userName;
    }
    public String getmuserName() {
        return muserName;
    }
}
```

I have a code for add users to `usersList` when they online:

```
onlineViewersCountRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    ArrayList<UsersOnlineClass> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
    UsersOnlineAdapter usersAdapter = new UsersOnlineAdapter(Chat.this, usersList);
    ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        usersList.add(new UsersOnlineClass(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()));
        lv.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
        Toast.makeText(Chat.this, String.valueOf(usersList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

It works Ok.

But I don't know how to remove user from `usersList` when it go offline. I tried this code:

```
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String deletedUser = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++) {
                if (usersList.get(i).equals(deletedUser)) {
                    usersList.remove(i);
                }
            }
```

But it does not work, the position is not deleted from the `usersList`. String `deletedUser` is equals one of positions in `usersList` (for example, *Micle*), it's Ok, but position not deleted.

Please help me. **How to remove entry from ArrayList in sync with Firebase Database?**

Comment: Do you want to delete user from database as well or just from `ArrayList`?

Comment: From firebase entry deleting when user go offline, it work. I need delete same entry from arraylist.

Comment: Did you try with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after removing? Also put `breakpoint` on `usersList.remove(i)` check will compiler hit `breakpoint`

Comment: Yes, I,m trying it. With debug I see, that position not removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in part: `usersList.get(i).equals(deletedUser)` - this returns an object which you want to compare to a `String` so block of code inside `if` statement is never executed because `equals` fails. So you need to compare two (custom) objects of same `type` or you can compare `String` to a `String` for example:

```
public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UsersOnlineClass deletedUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(UsersOnlineClass.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < usersList.size(); i++) {
            if (usersList.get(i).getmuserName().equals(deletedUser.getmuserName())) {
                usersList.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, it works.I did the same thing you suggested, a couple of seconds before your answer :)